# VBA: Why are the defined DAY values returning "30"?

Tags: vba, date, calendar

I've created a worksheet on which a month can be generated by inserting the first day of the needed month. User inserts "01/01/2017" in B4, clicks a button, the month (January) is filled out and the values within the table (C4:I34) are removed. The VBA code linked to that button goes as follows:

```
Sub CalReset()
'
' CalReset Macro
'
'
Dim DayOne As Integer
Dim DayTwo As Integer
Dim DayThree As Integer

DayOne = Day(B32)
DayTwo = Day(B33)
DayThree = Day(B34)
MsgBox (DayOne & " " & DayTwo & " " & DayThree) 'I used this to check what values I was getting for the days, the message box returns "30 30 30".

    Range("B4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B4:B34"), Type:=xlFillSeries
    Range("C4:I34").ClearContents
    If DayOne <= "3" Then Range("B32").ClearContents
    If DayTwo <= "3" Then Range("B33").ClearContents
    If DayThree <= "3" Then Range("B34").ClearContents
End Sub
```

The idea is to avoid dates of the next month. For example, if 01/02/2017 is used as a starting point, it'll fill in February (28 days) so the macro should remove March 1, 2 & 3 in corresponding cells B32, B33 & B34 (is smaller than or equals 3).

Why is the definition "Day(B32)" returning "30" while I'm seeing "01/03/2017" in that cell? It should return "1".
Note that dates are in European format, DD/MM/YYYY. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel uses a data system where day #1 is 0 January 1900 (or 31 December 1899 if you like), so day #0 is 30 December 1899.

So `Day(B32)`, where the variable `B32` has never been assigned a value and therefore still contains a default value of `0`, will return 30 (i.e. the day portion of 30 December 1899).

You were probably wanting to use `Day(Range("B32").Value)`, or `Day([B32])`.

---

```
Sub CalReset()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("B4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B4:B34"), Type:=xlFillSeries
        .Range("C4:I34").ClearContents
        If Day(.Range("B32").Value) <= 3 Then .Range("B32").ClearContents
        If Day(.Range("B33").Value) <= 3 Then .Range("B33").ClearContents
        If Day(.Range("B34").Value) <= 3 Then .Range("B34").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for explaining. That does work but leaves me with one strange behavior. When running the code for a month with lesser days compared to the previously generated month, it doesn't remove the values it should be removing. It does remove them if I run the code again. Strange.

Comment: @Timmmmaaahh Your code is setting the `DayOne` etc variables before you do the `AutoFill`, so it is using out-of-date values by the time the variables are used.  You should just use something like `If Day(Range("B32").Value) <= 3 Then Range("B32").ClearContents` (after the `AutoFill`).

Comment: Oh, snap! Of course, that was just silly. I changed the order of things, works great now.

Comment: @Timmmmaaahh I added the refactored code into the answer too.